not able to add or update fileds which is added manually in mailwizz tables
i am getting strange issue, i am using mailwizz extension, i added 4 fields in customer company table, those fields are state,way,mc and subscribers, this is my controller where i am storing data
$company->attributes = (array)request()->getPost($company->getModelName(), []); 
        $company->customer_id = (int)$lastID;
        $company->name = $request->getPost('companyName');
        $company->address_1 = $request->getPost('houseNumber');
        $company->address_2 = $request->getPost('street');
        $company->zip_code = $request->getPost('zipCode');
        $company->city = $request->getPost('city');
        $company->state = $request->getPost('state');
        $company->country_id = $request->getPost('country');
        $company->way = $request->getPost('way');
        $company->mc = implode(',',$request->getPost('mc'));
        $company->subscribers = $request->getPost('subscribers');

        try {
            $company->save(false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($company->getErrors());
            die;
        }

and this is my model file
class CustomerCompany extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public $state;
    public $way = '';
    public $mc = '';
    public $subscribers = '';
    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{customer_company}}';
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            ['name, country_id, address_1, city, zip_code', 'required', 'on' => 'insert, update, register'],

            ['name, vat_number', 'length', 'max' => 100],
            ['website', 'length', 'max' => 255],
            ['website', 'url'],
            ['country_id, zone_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true, 'min' => 1],
            ['address_1, address_2, city,state,mc,subscribers,country_id', 'length', 'max' => 255],
            ['zone_name', 'length', 'max' => 150],
            ['zip_code', 'length', 'max' => 10],
            ['phone, fax', 'length', 'max' => 32],
            ['type_id', 'exist', 'attributeName' => null, 'className' => CompanyType::class],
            ['country_id', 'exist', 'attributeName' => null, 'className' => Country::class],
            ['zone_id', 'exist', 'attributeName' => null, 'className' => Zone::class],
            ['phone, fax', 'match', 'pattern' => '/[0-9\s\-]+/'],
            //['state,mc,subscribers,way','safe']
        ];

        return CMap::mergeArray($rules, parent::rules());
    }
}

can anyone please help me why i am not able add or update those 4 new field,  i am using mailwizz, which is built in yii2

Do you get any sort of info in the debug log file? Check that your DB has fields type that you send to store, i mean when store letters to the int field. Some times DB false and you get nothing on the app level.

You shouldn't declare properties in model class for fields that exist in DB table.
